# Need help identifying a connector and someone who sells it

Tags: connector, identification

I have an evaluation board I need to connect to, and the connector is one I have not seen before.

I believe it is a LS2-120-01-F-D-RA1: [2.00 mm Locking Hermaphroditic Terminal/Socket Strip](https://www.samtec.com/products/ls2)

The connector on my board has two retainer clips, not one as in the SEMTEC drawings, but the dimensions overall seem to check out.

If it indeed is LS2-120-01-F-D-RA1, I'm having trouble finding anyone stocking it. I've tried Farnell, Mouser and DigiKey...

[image: Connector front]
[image: Connector back]
[image: BOM entry]

Comment: order online thru Samtec

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer of the eval board? They should at least be able to tell you the P/N of the connector on the board, if not the mating connector.

Comment: The evaluation board should have some PDFs with the info. And Samtec could Provide samples, or sell you one, or point you to the right reseller.

Comment: Aside from that, this is a standard 0.1" header spacing. You can use male to female jumper wire on the top, male to male on the bottom, or f to f and f to m. Nothing difficult for this header.

Comment: @Passerby I can use the male to male on the bottom alright, but for the top row the diameter of pins is a bit too small to grip on the connectors on the male to female jumper wires that I have. There is also not enough room under the sheath to fit the jumper wires, I have to stretch it, so it does not work close to the edges where it is wrapped... It was worth a try though

Comment: http://www.newark.com/samtec/ls2-120-01-f-d-ra1/socket-2mm-right-angle-40-position/dp/85T5454

Comment: Usually evaluation boards have a BOM with them. Barring that, there may be a way to contact an application engineer.

Comment: Heh, that board looks very familiar... several of the evaluation kits I designed for Maxim Integrated a few years ago, use that exact same type of connector. I can't see enough of it from your photo, and you don't indicate what the part number is, but it sure looks like it could be the MAX5318EVKIT. The MAXINT1 (FPGA) board uses the Samtec LS2-120-01-S-D-RA1 and the EV kit board uses the Samtec LS2-120-01-S-D-RA2. The difference is one has the pins on the outer row and the other has the pins on the inner row. You can contact Sametc.com directly to request sample connectors.

Comment: Looks like 0.1". I would de-solder the header and solder a more common header in place. This would be the fastest solution

Comment: @MarkU Spot on! Thanks a bunch, I just ordered some samples from SAMTEC. Let's see how good this thing is!